# Angular 2 DI and TypeScript Inheritance‏

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, typescript1.8

I have two TS repository classes

1) InvoiceRepository
2) SalesReceiptRepositroy

Here is how there constructor looks like

**InvoiceRepository**

```
export class InvoiceRepository extends RepositoryBase {

    constructor(
        protected http: Http,
        protected toasterService: ToasterService,
        protected progressbarService: ProgressBarService,
        invocieType: InvoiceType = InvoiceType.Invoice,
        @Inject('ApiEndpoint') protected apiEndpoint: string) {

        super(toasterService, progressbarService);
        console.log(invocieType);
    }
}
```

**SalesReceiptRepositroy**

```
export class SalesReceiptsRepository extends InvoiceRepository {

    constructor(http: Http,
        toasterService: ToasterService,
        progressbarService: ProgressBarService,
        @Inject('ApiEndpoint') apiEndpoint: string) {


        super(http, toasterService, progressbarService, InvoiceType.InvoiceCC, apiEndpoint);
    }
}
```

Questions:

1) I’m inheriting `SalesReceiptRepository` from `InvoiceRepository`, I have to pass all the required parameters to `super` class `constructor`. Would Angular separately `inject` dependency to Base class and Derived class when `SalesReceiptRepoistory` object get’s created? OR The base class will take from it’s derived class? Little confuse, please briefly explain how these two works together

2) If you look at the `InvocieRepository` constructor 3rd `parameter`, `InvoiceType` is an `enum` and I’m defaulting it to first value. But in the `console` statement, it’s logging value `api/` which is actually the value of 4th `parameter`. So, what it’s doing, setting both 3rd and 4th parameter value to `api/` where the 3rd one should be `1`. This is only happening when `InvoiceRepository` object get’screated, however it behaves well when `SalesReceipRepository` object get’s created. Why?

Comment: 2) Why did you add this parameter in the first place? Did you provide `provide(InvoiceType: {useValue: InvoiceType.SomeItem})` somewhere?

Comment: No, I want it to be set it to some default value when `InvoiceRepository` instance created by DI. However in case of `SalesReceiptRepository`, I manually calling the base class `constructor` so it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: I see. I guess you would need to add `?` at the end (`invocieType?: InvoiceType = ...`)of the parameter name to mark it as optional. It might also be necessary to move optional parameters at the end of the parameter list (not sure about this).

Comment: I moved the optional param to last and tried the above but getting compiled time error `Parameter can not have question mark and Initializer`

Comment: Also tried by removing the `question mark` but then getting run time error `No provider for Number`

Comment: I don't know TS very well (I'm using Dart). According to the error message I would try `invoiceType?:InvoiceType` without the default value `=...` and then in the constructor add `this.invoiceType = invoiceType || InvoiceType.Invoice`

Comment: Yeah, that could work but I put `@Optional` decorator  and that seems to work. But I still can not assign the default value though and getting `null` which is not a big deal.

Comment: Right, Stupid me :face-palm:

Answer (score 1):

Angular will inject just in the derived class, so because of this you needed to repass every parameter to the super constructor. To better understand the situation I need to see where and how you provide this services, because the code appears absolutelly right.